# Count distinct values based on conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

| Category | Score | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 96 | 1 |
| A | 95 | 1 |
| A | 95 | 2 |
| A | 95 | 2 |
| B | 96 | 2 |
| B | 95 | 2 |
| B | 96 | 2 |
| C | 97 | 3 |
| C | 96 | 3 |
| C | 97 | 3 |

For each category, I want a count of the distinct IDs that have 2 scores (or more) of < 97. So, based on this data, my end goal result would be a dataframe or list that looks like:

| Category | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 0 |

Comment: How is your dataset structured? pls provide a code sample

Comment: Why Category `A` ID `2` is counted even there is only one score less then 97?

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't. I adjusted the table without the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a nested groupby to get the count of unique `ID` in each `Category` group.

```py
out = (df[df['Score'].lt(97)]
       .groupby('Category')
       .apply(lambda g: g.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)['ID'].nunique())
       .to_frame('Count')
       .reset_index())
# or
out = (df[df['Score'].lt(97)]
       .groupby(['Category', 'ID'])
       .filter(lambda g: len(g) >= 2)
       .groupby(['Category'])['ID'].nunique()
       .reindex(df['Category'].unique(), fill_value=0)
       .to_frame('Count')
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

  Category  Count
0        A      2
1        B      1
2        C      0
```

Comment: Thank you! This suits me well and I believe gives the right numbers.